# asp.net core render a view into stringwriter

Tags: asp.net-core

So I want to build an Html custom builder which passes a model object to a partial view and renders the page into a StringWriter

```
        public static class HtmlExtensions
        {
            public static HtmlString BuildTextboxFor(this IHtmlHelper helper, object model)
            {
            //Find the partial view and pass the Model through it.

            //Render the page into a StringWriter

            //return new HtmlString(StringWriter object);
            }
        }
```

The models name will be the name of the partial. I can't seem to find a solution for .NET CORE. All the resources seem to be for ASP.NET Framework.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `@await Html.PartialAsync("PartialName", viewModel)` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial)?

Comment: This maybe be another way. Is there a way I can render it the way above?

Comment: Not easily, The `HtmlHelper` is generally just for using in the context of  razor view.  If you are looking for a way to render Razor views to a strings you could try https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IHtmlHelper.Partial` returns `IHtmlContent`, `HtmlString` is just another implementation of the same abstraction.  Looking at your sample code this is the desired result (not a `StringWriter`)

```
public static HtmlString BuildTextboxFor(this IHtmlHelper helper, object model) {
    return helper.Partial($"~/Views/{model.GetType().Name}.cshtml", model)
}
```

If you still want to write the view to a `StringWriter` its not a problem:

```
var content = helper.Partial($"~/Views/{model.GetType().Name}.cshtml", model);
using(var writer = new StringWriter()) {
    content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
}
```